# .Net COM Interop get running COM instance and assign it to RCW

Tags: com, interop

I am creating a wpf application which need to interop with a third party tool(COM). the tool will be launched first and I will give some input in the tool. then he will launch my wpf application where again some input will be given.my wpf app need to interop with the running instance of a tool and execute some methods in the tool and get the result to my app.I tried using RCW. but RCW is just a proxy. I need a running instance of a tool to interact with. Can anybody help me out????????????

**Edit:** There is existing C++ code which does this, so how can this be translated to C#?

```
bool DisDriver::Create(CLSID clsid, DWORD ClsContext, LPCTSTR ServerName) 
{ 
    hRet = ::CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid,NULL,dwClsContext,strServerName==NULL?NULL:(&svrinfo),1,&multiqi); 

    if(hRet!=S_OK) { 
#ifdef XYDISPDRIVER_DEBUG
         _tprintf(_T("CoCreateInstance failed:"),hRet); 
#endif 
        return false; 
    } 
    pDisp = (IDispatch*)(multiqi.pItf); 

}
```

Comment: Look into the Running Object Table (ROT). If the tool does not register with the ROT then you are out of luck.

Comment: hi Ben, thank you for you response. when I try to use Marshal.getactiveobject(programid), it throws error instead of looking into ROT for the active object of the program and return it. So does it mean this object is not there in ROT? or it can be other causes?

Comment: Also I tried to enumerate thru all running objects, I could not get the needed object

Comment: You will have to come up with another way. Does the third party tool accept plugins for example? Could you launch it via COM to begin with so you already have the data? Finally could you use the UI Automation to interact with the tool? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx

Comment: I dont think it accepts pluggin.But another C++ application  already communicates with the same tool which was done using Cocreateinstance() method by supplying progid,clsid and server name parameters.Is there something silmilar in the .Net as well?

Comment: If the third party tool registers a class factory, then you can do the same. Why don't you try that?

Comment: I tried using Marshal.getactiveobject(progid) which throws error saying operation unavailable

Comment: Isn't the equivalent in C# we can try?or will there be any other cause for that error?

Comment: you should just create the object in the usual way. If the third party took as registered a class factory then you will connect to the existing instance of the application..

Comment: Thank you.I tried that.I am able to create com instance using Type.gettype(progid),activator.createinstance(type).but can you help me on how to find/map the existing instance to this instance?

Comment: If you have an instance why can you not use that? Further explanation is required on your part.

Comment: I am able to create a new com instance.but how can I assign this instance to the already running instance? because the user will enter some input in the tool directly.So only if I get the existing instance, then only I will be able to read the tool instance input.I need to invoke a method in the tool instance.

Comment: You cannot do that. Depending on the tool and the facilities it offers, you may be able to achieve what you want in another way. What is the tool?

Comment: You said "But another C++ application already communicates with the same tool which was done using Cocreateinstance() method by supplying progid,clsid and server name parameters".... Can you post a code snippet showing how they did it? That approach can no doubt be translated to C#.

Comment: Its a big class.. Do u want me to put it?

Comment: but these two methods are actually doing the job

Comment: Also they are using idispatch interface

Comment: That's a bog-standard basic CoCreateInstanceEx. They are doing nothing special at all - simply doing what C#.Net does when you say `Type.GetType(progid);Activator.CreateInstance(type)`.

Comment: but I am not getting how they map the running instance with the created one.they are also using Idispatch interface to know the type at runtime.

Comment: Will it be working if we get the dll out of this C++ class and use it in our .Net app?

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation for the product to work out how to do this. You are successfully connecting to the application. Then what were you going to do? Read the documentation as it is all product-specific from there.

Comment: hmm...but not to the already running instance right which is my issue?

Comment: It will work the same as the other application. If the C++ code you referred to is getting the running instance so will you!

Comment: sure Ben. will try that and let you know. Thank you very much for your time and patience :)

Comment: Cheers.just two lines works... Unbelievable.thanks Ben :)

Comment: Type.GetType(progid);Activator.CreateInstance(type)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit the relevant information into the question and/or answer, or even post new answers with new details if that is warranted. The comment section of a question/answer is only meant for relevant information regarding the actual post at hand, like mistakes, requests for more details, etc. not for long discussions even though they may be helpful to the people involved. If you need to continue this discussion, consider taking it to a chat room instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Type.GetType(prog.id),Activator.CreateInstance(type)` will actually get the running instance of a com program which is the required one for this issue.